# determine if a given point is inside the polygon

Tags: computational-geometry

Given a convex polygon as a counter-clockwise list of n vertices, give O(lgn) algorithm to determine if a given point is inside the polygon. Assume the basic operations take O(1).

I am think a direction that: if a point is inside a convex polygon, what is the special relationship among the points and all the vertecies or edges? Also, I am guessing the trick here is the convex polygon which makes the algorithm lgn.

Comment: here's a hint think of drawing an infinite line from that point towards the polygon if it's outside or in any direction if it's inside, how many intersections does the line have? I believe that will answer your question.

Comment: @Jesus Ramos: That algorithm is applicable to *any* polygon (not just convex ones) and it is `O(n)`. In this case the whole point is to come up with `O(lg n)` algorithm by using the fact that the polygon is *convex*.

Comment: @Jesus, am I missing something? AFAIK, your suggestion is `O(n)`, not `O(log(n))`.

Comment: see: http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/

Comment: @Bart Andrey's answer is the hint I was getting at, I usually don't like to give away the answer to these types of problems, I like to make people think a little bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only solution for this problem I know of requires `O(n)` polygon *preprocessing* time. Afterwards each query point against a preprocessed polygon is handled in `O(lg n)` time.

Just take a point `P` inside the polygon (let's call it "pole") and for each vertex draw a ray exiting from `P` and passing through the vertex. Consider this to be a polar coordinate system with origin at `P`, with the entire polar plane subdivided into sectors by these rays. Now, given your query point, you just need to convert it to polar coordinates with origin at our pole `P`. Then just perform binary search to determine the specific sector that contains the query point. The final inside/outside check within the sector (point vs. edge side test) is a trivial `O(1)` operation. Each query is handled in `O(lg n)` time needed for binary search.

This approach will actually work with a larger class of polygons than just convex ones. It covers the class of so called *star-shaped* polygons, i.e. polygons that have a point from which the whole interior of the polygon can be "seen" or "observed".

The `O(n)` preprocessing time comes from the need to determine the location of the pole in advance.

**P.S.** I got to carried away thinking about more general case. If your polygon is convex,  you can simply use any of its vertices as the pole. That way you get a `O(lg n)` algorithm right away, no preprocessing required.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check this link with detailed info how to determine whether a point is inside a complex polygon, including sample (c) code.

http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

Answer (score 0):

The condition for a point to be inside a polygon is that the point should be on same side of all line segments. You should check for the *sign* of the distance of the point in question with each line segments that make up the polygon - if all are same sign the point is inside the polygon. A google search should give you many algorithms.

Comment: But that is an `O(n)` algorithm, not a `O(log(n))` one.

Comment: Doesn't satisfy the requirement, since it is `O(n)` complexity.