# Detect if point in Latitude/Longitude based Polygon

Tags: c#, .net, maps, latitude-longitude

I'd like to detect, on the server side using C# only, whether a Latitude/Longitude based coordinate is within an area (polygon) made up of Latitude/Longitude based points. I believe the right way to do this is raycasting, but maybe there is already a C# implementation out there as it's not trivial?

Also, I understand that SQL Server has some geometry function such as `STIntersects` but in order to use that I need both SQL Server 2008 running and every check would involve a database connection which is undesirable.

Comment: A Rather more generic algorithm would be to ask, or search for "How to detect if a point falls inside an irregularly shaped polygon".  I dont actually know, I could probably write something from scratch, but it certainly wouldn't be the most efficient piece of code...not at first anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since a sphere is a locally diffeomorphic to the plane, you can use any algorithm that works on the cartesian plane, e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223909/determine-if-a-given-point-is-inside-the-polygon).  You'll only have to do work translating coordinates if your polygon includes a pole.  Depending on your use case, maybe you can reject those inputs.

Comment: Probably worth noting here that geometries crossing the 180 meridian (ie. the point where the cartesian plane doesn't wrap but the globe does) can be something of a headache as well. Point-in-polygon for GIS needs to be 180-wrap-aware otherwise you can end up getting very odd results.

Answer (score 0):

I putzed around on the internet for a bit and found [this link](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/).

The example is written in C, but looks like it could very easily be adapted to work with C# and Long/Lat coordinates.  You would need to keep in mind the crossover lines though (NS/EW), and add code to compensate where necessary, either that or make a decimal conversion of the LatLong values before running the function (West and South are represented with values < 0).