# Visibility of 2 vertices in a simple polygon

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

I'm working on a small application with the P5 library that allow a user to click on a canvas to create points and build a polygon and I want to compute the visibility graph of that polygon.
How can I implement an algorithm that can tell me if 2 vertices are visible in this polygon ? 
I don't know how to check if a line between these 2 vertices is inside the polygon. 
thank you.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5223909/266535

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1119627/266535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let *a* and *b* be two vertices. First check that the segment *ab* is locally inside at *a*, and at *b*. I.e., it falls within the cone determined by the vertices before and after *a*, and *b*. If so, then you need to intersect the segment *ab* with each edge of the polygon (except those incident to *a* and to *b*, because you just checked those).

For this you need segment-segment intersection code. 
You can find this all over the web, including in Chapter 7 of [*Computational Geometry in C*](http://cs.smith.edu/~jorourke/books/compgeom.html),
and [this description by Martin Thoma](https://martin-thoma.com/how-to-check-if-two-line-segments-intersect/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have a link that could help me to implement the part where I need to determine if the segment is locally inside at a and b. I have a problem in the case where the angle formed by the incident vertices is obtuse.

Comment: You want one vertex to the left of *ab* and one vertex to the right. So it can be checked with two calls to a LeftOf( ) function that takes three points as input and returns true iff the 1st pt is left of the line determined by the 2nd & 3rd. This is essentially the [signed area of a triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help.